# Data type consistency

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-processing, bigdata

Did anyone run into a problem where all data have **string values** and you need to know the **actual data type**?

How did you go about solving this problem and which tools/libraries were used?

For example, "1" is int, "05/2017" is a date with month and year. The problem is that data comes from multiple feeds and fields can have any data.

Comment: Is your question "how to turn my raw data into meaningful input for my ML algo"?

Comment: I say, Yes. Also, we solved the problem by using some Regular Expressions and ML.  I'm really interested in knowing how other people solved it and what tools were used. I tried to find how others solved the problem, but could not really find something really good. I saw Google Cloud introduced Dataprep. I'm surprised that there's not much information about it. Since IoT is becoming huge, ML is growing, companies should receive a lot of unstructured and unknown data types. Companies use ML for classifications and if they know the proper data type your ML algorithm can perform better too.

Comment: I guess most of companies have to spend time and days profiling and understanding their data. After the data was profiled and something was changed again, the profiling starts from the beginning, creating huge waste of time and overhead.

Comment: All data science platforms I know (RapidMiner, dataiku, knime,...) have tools helping users  to prepare its data.